# @Data in project lombok is recognize but not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

Using - 
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Maven - 3.3.9

Just import project lombok to my project.

[image]

The following picture is my class before adding @Data 
[image]

And after -

[image]

The wired thing is that eclipse adds the import automatically, and it seems that lombok has been recognized but I still dont get all the getters/setters and so on.
(look at the Outline window in the right, nothing changed).

notes - 
1. I tried to restart eclipse (even exit and get in and not only restart)
2. I pressed on project > maven > update project.
3. I refresh it couple of times.

Thanks For reading!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was I didnt install project-lombok.
You need to go to the folder where the jar file is saved and run `java -jar lombok-1.6.18.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to install it manually.try to do these:

1. copy  lombok.jar to the directery of myeclipse.ini / eclipse.ini
2. open eclipse.ini / myeclipse.ini，insert this two words to  the last
   ：

   ```
   -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
   -javaagent:lombok.jar
   ```

   3.restart  eclipse / myeclipse

Comment: @Paz are u still facing issue ?

Comment: `-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar` is no longer needed.